# How to hide thoes children elements that exceed the paraent's width in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The parent has red dashed border, and the children elements are filled with blue. It can be implemented by `inline-block`, `float`, `flex`, etc.
[image]

I want to implement such effect: when the parent's width gets too small to contain the last children element, then the last element will be hidden.
How to implement this with pure CSS or with minimal JavaScript?

Comment: Are the children width known or not?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this using `max-width`, `max-height` and `overflow`, like the example below:

```css
.parent {
   max-width: 400px;
   max-height: 60px;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

.child {
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   margin: 5px;
   background-color: blue;
   display: inline-block;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>There are 5 items here</p>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">1</div>
   <div class="child">2</div>
   <div class="child">3</div>
   <div class="child">4</div>
   <div class="child">5</div>
</div>
```

And here is another example using `flex` instead of `display: inline block`; with `max-width`, `max-height` and `overflow` too

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  max-width: 380px;
  max-height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<pAnother example, using flex, with 5 items too</p>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your html structure is static, you can try to look into media queries.
Otherwise, i'm not sure it would be possible in CSS.

Using overflow: hidden on your parent element will not make the last child desappear until it totaly overflow.

Comment: It's not static. The parent width is changeable. If it's not possible in pure CSS, is it any simple way to do it in js?

Comment: Not in a simply way. You could try to get each child and add their width document.getElementById("child").offsetWidth then check if it's greater than the parent width

Answer (score -1):

Setting the overflow property of the parent container to hidden can do that for you.

Comment: No. The overflow property only hides the part that exceeds the parent. What I want is that hide the whole child element even only part of it overflowes.

Comment: You can set flex-wrap property of the container to wrap. e.g. <code>flex-wrap: wrap</code>
Then you add overflow: hidden too.